# Tomcat 8.5.43 - shutdown.sh does not stop process

Tags: shutdown, tomcat

Team,
we are using **Tomcat 8.5.43**,
it starts application perfectly but while using shutdown.sh it does not work,  I mean it gives below

```
[alfresco@ind785 bin]$ ./shutdown.sh
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /opt/alfresco/alfresco-6.2.2/tomcat
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /opt/alfresco/alfresco-6.2.2/tomcat
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /opt/alfresco/alfresco-6.2.2/tomcat/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /opt/alfresco/alfresco-6.2.2/java
Using CLASSPATH:       /opt/alfresco/alfresco-6.2.2/tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar:/opt/alfresco/alfresco-6.2.2/tomcat/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
NOTE: Picked up JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS:  --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Ignoring option PermSize; support was removed in 8.0
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Ignoring option MaxPermSize; support was removed in 8.0
Jul 20, 2021 1:17:27 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina stopServer
SEVERE: Could not contact [localhost:[8005]]. Tomcat may not be running.
Jul 20, 2021 1:17:27 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina stopServer
SEVERE: Catalina.stop:
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
        at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:399)
        at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:242)
        at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:224)
        at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:403)
        at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:609)
        at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:558)
        at java.base/java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:454)
        at java.base/java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:231)
```

It is fresh installation of tomcat, nothing changed.
I need to kill PID manually every time, instead shutdown.sh itself able to kill it proper way.

**Note :** I am using  OpenJDK11U-jdk_x64_linux_11.0.7_10.tar.gz   as a JDK

Regarding port 8005, I confirmed with my unix team, it does not require opening from IPTables as its to local only. And same works fine with older version tomcat 7

Any configuration changes or any changes needed let me know.

Comment: Did the tomcat start up sucessfully? Did you alter your syntax to match the new 8.5 configuration? Also note that your tomcat version is quite old and is affected by ghostcat. Same for your java Version.

Comment: Try connecting to the port (e.g. `telnet localhost 8005`) and sending the magic word `SHUTDOWN` to debug the problem independently.